# Binding TreeView to DataSet

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, dataset

I have a dataset I created from an Oracle Query.
I get a datatable from a function and add it to dataset.

Now I try to bind to treeview to the ds.
My code Behind:

```
private void init_TreeView()
        { 

           //TreeViewItem parent = PM_TreeView.Items.Add("Requirements");
           DataTable dt  =  DataBases.RunQuery();
           dt.TableName = "REQ";
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           ds.Tables.Add(dt);
           //ds.Relations.Add("rsParentChild", ds.Tables["REQ"].Columns["RQ_REQ_ID"], ds.Tables["REQ"].Columns["RQ_FATHER_ID"]);
           var dataSet = ds;
           _rootNodes = dataSet.Tables["REQ"].DefaultView;
           _rootNodes.RowFilter = "RQ_FATHER_ID = -1";
           this.DataContext = this;
         }
```

And

```
private DataView _rootNodes;
```

And

```
public DataView RootNodes
{
    get { return _rootNodes; }
}
```

And my XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="PM_TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="445" Margin="44.847,68.285,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" Foreground="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FFBBB6B6" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="13.333">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding rsParentChild}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeDescription}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

My datatable is:

```
RQ_REQ_ID RQ_FATHER_ID RQ_REQ_NAME
0         -1           REQ
1          0           QC11
```

But I get nothing on the treeview

Comment: are you sure about your binding and result of query?

Comment: @DJ I can put here the query result, and you can see that this is the exact table I get, but I'm not sure on the binding, I tried several way to bind, this is the last I tried.

Comment: can you move your code to loaded event from init event and try?

Comment: I move it to the constructor of the UC but still no binding

Comment: u need to check ur binding first. can you put `<TextBock Text={Binding RootNodes}/>` in xaml and see what it is displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
    <TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

and within my window i have:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Data");

        DataTable t = new DataTable("Table");
        t.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { t.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(int)) };
        t.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
        t.Columns.Add("Father", typeof(int));
        ds.Tables.Add(t);

        ds.Relations.Add("Parents", t.Columns["Key"], t.Columns["Father"], false);

        t.Rows.Add(1, "First", -1);
        t.Rows.Add(2, "Second", -1);
        t.Rows.Add(3, "Third", 2);

        Root = new DataView(t);
        Root.RowFilter = "[Father]<0";
        t.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Father] < 0";

        tv.DataContext = this;
```

where `Root` ist declared as:

```
public DataView Root { get; private set; }
```

The results are as expected.

Comment: Hi 10x for your answer, when I run the next row:`ds.Relations.Add("Parents", dt.Columns["RQ_REQ_ID"], dt.Columns["RQ_FATHER_ID"]);`  I get:**This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values.** I checked the table dt and its the exact table mentioned above

Comment: did you know how to fix the exception maybe? 10x:)

Comment: after 1 week of debug i found the problem! 10x!!